# Mysql dump from old server

Tags: ip, mysql

I have to clean up as mess for a client.

The DNS record of the domain has been moved to a different server (IP address). But I need to retrieve MySQL data from the old server. I still have the ip address of the old server.

Problem is that there was never a administration software like phpmyadmin.

I have the username, password, database name and host(localhost) for the database on the old server.

How do I do this?

Comment: What was the method by which you had accessed earlier ? what command/tool did you use ?

Comment: I didn't. I inherited a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the mysql client on your machine, you *should* be able to just

```
bash#  mysqldump -h[ipAddress] -u[username] -p  [dbname]  > outfile.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin can access servers other than localhost.